# Sphinx build failing on ReadTheDocs

Tags: python, python-sphinx, documentation-generation, read-the-docs

I'm trying to build the documentation for [a project](https://github.com/usnistgov/sesame) using ReadTheDocs. The Sphinx build script is failing with: `error: option -T not recognized`. I double checked the [Sphinx documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html#id7), and the `-T` option has been available since version 1.2. (ReadTheDocs is building with version 1.6.5). Is there a setting I need to change in `docs/conf.py`, or a setting on the ReadTheDocs project page?

Full screenshot of the error message:
[image]

Comment: I think that's a misleading error. Your earlier builds with `-T` are successful. Your builds started failing after this commit https://github.com/usnistgov/sesame/commit/fce42e5ccc61a94c2eb46b55b98751ce08a03f86 Try reverting previous to that commit.

Comment: @StevePiercy I removed the line you specified and tried again, same result.

Comment: Here's what I found: Compare the [last successful build](https://readthedocs.org/projects/sesame/builds/7096742/) to the [first failed build](https://readthedocs.org/projects/sesame/builds/7096829/). Note that the commit hashes are identical, so the failure cannot be in your repo or code. To verify that assumption, can you build docs on your machine? It indicates to me that you made a configuration change in your RTD project Admin at April 25, 2018. 10:47 a.m Pacific time. What you did to cause this, I have no clue. Hopefully that points you in the right direction or jogs your memory

Comment: I think I see something. There is a new step in the failed build `python setup.py install --force` before it even reaches `cat doc/conf.py`. So what I think happened is that you added a requirements file and toggled on under *Admin > Advanced Settings > Install Project: Install your project inside a virtualenv using setup.py install*. Another possibility to try is to do a Wipe of this version of your docs under *Versions > Branch > Wipe*.